# Playing audio from MediaStore on a Media Player Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, mediastore

Is there a way to play audio obtained from MediaStore through the use of the MediaPLayer, Or am I going in the completely wrong direction? I've looked and MediaStore.Audio so far but nothing is really helping me. I just need to know if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I assume you have basic knowledge of querying a ContentProvider and working with Cursors. If you dont, I suggest you research it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Once you have a basic knowledge of how to use a ContentProvider, query the URI `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for the column `Audio.Media.DATA`, along with any other fields you need.

Let's say you put the returned cursor in `yourCursor`

```
String path = yourCursor.getString(getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DATA));

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(path);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

That's a very basic implementation. Get comfy with the android docs if you need to get fancy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the bundled music application source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music

1. List music using content providers
2. Use MediaPlayer in order to play the file you will get from the cursor

You also have examples on the android developer website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html